# What is the best procedure to move SharePoint 2007 (WSS 3.0) to a new server?

Tags: 2007, migration

Our SharePoint 2007 (WSS 3.0) instance is on the same server as our Report Services. I've been tasked with moving the SharePoint portion to a new VM. Current environment is Server 2003/SQL 2005 and new environment will be 2008r2/SQL 2008. The plan is to backup and restore the content database on the new server, install SharePoint, make the needed changes and validate.

I know there's work to be done to the database since it's living on a new server. I believe some of the 12 hive will need to be copied over as well (_layout, images, etc).

Any advice or sources to help with this project?

Answer (score 0):

Apart of the customization's you have done with your SharePoint, no need to copy any element from 12 hive. Simply install SharePoint on new server and follow the same steps you mentioned (backup/restore database and then reattach to SharePoint). In case you have any customization's in SharePoint (i.e custom solutions, web parts etc), you have to deploy the same solution package in new SharePoint environment or do the changes manually if its not the part of any solution pkg.

As an advice, i would suggest you to first try the same procedure with a new DEV/UAT SharePoint VM's and then move to production SharePoint VM. The error chances will be decreased in this processes.

Good Luck